# Input de Data retornando Hora junto com a data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, twitter-bootstrap

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que retornasse apenas a Data, mas não sei o que fazer!
Meu código:

```
[Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe sua data de nascimento.")]
    public System.DateTime dtNascimento { get; set; }
```

Utilizo um JQuery pra deixar o input bonito e tal...
Código:

```
$("#dtNascimentoFuncMeusDados").removeAttr("data-val-date");
$('#dtNascimentoFuncMeusDados').datepicker({
    weekStart: 0,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    language: "pt-BR",
    multidate: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mude sua propriedade para `string` na sua `ViewModel`.

```
public string dtNascimento { get; set; }
```

Se ela for do tipo `Datetime` ela sempre irá solicitar data e hora. Na model ela pode e deve ser do tipo `Datetime` e quando for converter da `ViewModel` para `Model` (entidade) você faz as validações necessárias.